# How to get the selected id from kendo grid row and populate it to the controls using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, selecteditem, selectedindex

I have a Kendo grid which i have added some dummy data and also added edit button inside Kendo grid. when i click edit button it open popup model that i have created and it works fine. No i want to be able to click on edit button and get the selected row id and load the data on the respective text boxes.

I have followed this [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/MuDX7/) and am not getting it correctly,but in my case i want it on a button click and load on textboxes

**Kendo Grid**

```
 //Model starts here
        (function () {
            var People = [{ Id: 1,firstName: "E", lastName: "Es" }, 
                          { Id: 2, firstName: "J", lastName: "Js" },
                          { Id: 3, firstName: "J", lastName: "Js" },
                          { Id: 4, firstName: "G", lastName: "Gp" },
                          { Id: 5, firstName: "ZKZG", lastName: "RD" }];

            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: 
                {
                    data: People
                },
                pageable: { pageSize: 10, buttonCount: 5 },
                height: 400,
                resizable: true,
                columnMenu: true,
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: { mode: "multiple" },
                columns: [

                    { template: '<input type="button" class="info  k-button k-button-icontext" id="btnEdit" name="info" value="Edit"  style="height: 26px; margin: 0px 2px; min-width: 64px;" />' },
                    { Id:1, title: "First Name", field: "firstName" },
                    { Id: 2, title: "Last Name", field: "lastName" },
                    { Id: 3, title: "Surname", field: "firstName" },
                    { Id: 4, title: "Province", field: "firstName" },
                    { Id: 5, title: "City", field: "firstName" },
                ],

            })
        })();

        //model her
        $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').tbody.find('.info').click(function () {
            OpenDialog(); here am calling my modelview

             //I was trying to follow the example from the link

            $(grid.tbody).on("click", "td", function (e) {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var rowIdx = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);
            var colIdx = $("td", row).index(this);
            var item = grid.dataItem(row);
            var id = item.Id;
            alert("row:" + rowIdx + " col:" + colIdx + " id:" + id + "\nitem:" + JSON.stringify(item, null, 4));


        });
```

**View Model**

**Edit**

```
                <br />

                <div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>FirstName:</strong>
                        <input class="form-control" id="txtFirstName" type="text" /><br />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>txtLastName:</strong>
                        <input class="form-control" id="txtLastName" type="text" /><br />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Surname:</strong>
                        <input class="form-control" id="txtSurname" type="text" /><br />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Province:</strong>
                        <input class="form-control" id="txtProvince" type="text" /><br />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>City:</strong>
                        <input class="form-control" id="txtity" type="text" /><br />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="border-top: none;">
                <button class='btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right m-t-n-xs' type="submit" id="btnSave" onclick="SaveData()">Save changes</button>

                <button class='btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right m-t-n-xs' type="button" id="btnClose" style="margin:1px;" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="CloseDialog()">Close</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Calling viewModel on button Click**

```
  <script>

    $("#btnTesting").click(function () {
        OpenDialog();
    });

</script>
```